# Apply Knockout bindings after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the following script on my view:

```
<script>           
        MyObj.initModel(getUrl);            
        $(document).ready(function () {                
            ko.applyBindings(MyObj.viewModel, document.getElementById("someId")); 
        });
    </script>
```

Inside initModel(getUrl) i have ajax call, that on success sets my view model(MyObj.viewModel) using `ko.mapping.fromJS(response);`

That viewModel is binded to some partial view.

How to applyBindings only **AFTER** my ajax call is completed?

I tried something like this in my script on the view:

```
`$("#someId").ajaxComplete(function () { ko.applyBindings(MyObj.viewModel, document.getElementById("someId")); });`
```

But in this case i'm getting ko error about multiple times binding to the same element.

Comment: Have you tried $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});

Comment: see this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154475/93504

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var bindingCallback = function () {                
        ko.applyBindings(MyObj.viewModel, document.getElementById("someId")); 
    }; 

    MyObj.initModel(getUrl, bindingCallback);
});
```

then in your initModel, just call the bindingCallback method in the AJAX success method by adding something like `bindingCallback();` in it.

Comment: I would suggest this approach, but using the promise pattern you get for free using jquery's ajax call. no need to pass around callbacks nowadays for stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

My data load method is within my viewmodel so on success of the ajax call I just do apply bindings on self

```
ko.applyBindings(self, document.getElementById("someId"));
```

having declared self at the the top of my viewmodel

```
 var self = this;
```

Also, Since I just researched how to use the promise pattern from jquery ajax I thought i'd save the next monkey the bother.
So you just make the initModel return the result of the ajax call so you can use when() and then() thusly:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $.when(MyObj.initModel(getUrl)).then(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(MyObj.viewModel, document.getElementById("someId"));
    });
});

function MyObj() {
    this.initModel = function(getUrl){

         return $.ajax({url: getUrl});

    }
}
```

this is untested code